# what's the difference of the three installtion packet of Kayako?

Tags: php

what's the difference of the three installation packet of Kayko?

```
  fusion_stable_ioncubeclosed_4_01_179.tar.gz
  fusion_stable_zendclosed_4_01_179.tar.gz
 geoiplite_stable_bin_4_01_179.tar.gz
```

thank you.

Comment: That's an ... interesting ... question.  [Their software *starts* at at thousand dollars](http://www.kayako.com/signup/).  This should be a question you ask *them*, you'd better damn well get support with that amount of money paid.

Comment: I'm not sure what Kayko is but if I had to guess I would say they are libraries that are needed for the application but are written with licenses that prevent them from shipping with the original code.

Comment: Kayako is a support / knowledge base system. This question is, however, off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two would appear to be different versions of the software, one which works with ionCube Loader and one which works with Zend Optimizer. Your server likely only has one of these.

See [their docs](http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DOCS/PHP+decoders) on the subject.